# invalid.syntax aparece qdo o programa é executado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Já tentei colocar `palavra = ''` e o mesmo erro continua aparecendo:

```
lista = []
i = 0
while (palavra != 'Sair') or (palavra != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: ')
    lista.append(palavra)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Você está esquecendo um parêntese na linha `palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra'))`, por isso o erro de sintaxe :)

Comment: **Dica:** ao invés de usar a condição  `while (palavra != 'Sair') or (palavra != 'sair')`, pode usar o [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), desse jeito: `while (palavra.lower() != 'sair')`.

Comment: lista = []
i = 0
palavra = 'a'
while (palavra.lower != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
    lista.append(palavra)
print(lista)

Comment: depois das modificações o programa não para mesmo depois de digitar 'sair'.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda anterior

Comment: Estão faltando os parênteses do `lower()`, veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@tuxpilgrim/InterestingMindlessComputationalscience)

Comment: teria como fazer utilizando o while?

Comment: teria como fazer o programa sem utilizar o lower(), ou ele é obrigatório qdo o conteúdo da lista são strings?

Comment: favor desconsiderar a pergunta do while.

Comment: Só trocar o seu `or` por um `and`. Sugeri o `lower()` porque ele já vai pegar todas as possiblidades da palavra `sair`, atualizei no *replit* caso queira ver.

Comment: Se usar o `or` vai ser sempre `True` , logo não vai sair do *loop*. Adicionei três formas de contornar isso com o seu código, no *replit*.

Comment: estou tentando varrer a lista com a variável "proc_palavra", mas não funciona.

Comment: lista = []
i = 0
palavra = ''
while (palavra.lower() != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
    lista.append(palavra)
print(lista)
proc_palavra = int(input('digite a palavra que procura: '))
print(lista[proc_palavra])

Comment: Viu o link do *replit*? Acho que já saimos bastante do seu problema. Esse seu erro está dando porque está declarando `palavra` e a entrada está indo pra `proc_palavra` e não `palavra`.

Comment: eu só estou trabalhando, ao menos por enquanto, com a primeira forma que tu pôs.
não conheço as demais

Comment: quando eu fiz um exercício para buscar um numero na lista me foi dado o exemplo
posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
print(lista[posicao-1])

logo pensei que bastaria por str no lugar de int para começar a procurar palavra ao invés de número

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando o fechamento do parêntesis da conversão do input para string na seguinte linha:

```
palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: ')
```

Deveria ser:

```
palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Como já disseram, falta fechar os parênteses de [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str). Mas na verdade, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então `str` não é necessário neste caso.

Outra coisa é a condição do `while`. O `or` é verdadeiro se alguma das condições for verdadeira (se apenas uma dela for verdadeira, já é o suficiente). E enquanto a condição for verdadeira, o `while` continua executando.

Portanto, `(palavra != 'Sair') or (palavra != 'sair')` quer dizer "se a palavra não for 'Sair' **ou** se a palavra não for 'sair'". O que acontece então se a palavra for "Sair"?

- a primeira condição (`palavra != 'Sair'`) é falsa, pois a palavra é igual a "Sair"
- a segunda condição (`palavra != 'sair'`) é verdadeira, pois a palavra não é igual a "sair"

Como uma das condições é verdadeira, o resultado do `or` é verdadeiro, e por isso ele não sai do loop. Para corrigir, basta trocar `or` por `and`, pois o `and` só será verdadeiro se ambas as condições forem verdadeiras (se uma delas for falsa, ele sai do `while`):

```
while (palavra != 'Sair') and (palavra != 'sair'):
```

Ou então use [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) para converter a string para letras minúsculas, aí você só precisará comparar com "sair".

Outra coisa é que você não usa a variável `i` para nada, então pode tirá-la também.

Mas ainda tem um detalhe. Vendo o código abaixo (com as modificações sugeridas até então):

```
lista = []
palavra = ''
while palavra.lower() != 'sair':
    palavra = input('digite alguma palavra: ')
    lista.append(palavra)

print(lista)
```

O código acima inclui a palavra "sair" na lista, pois dentro do `while` a palavra é lida, adicionada na lista e só depois é verificada se ela é igual a "sair".

Caso não queira que a palavra "sair" esteja na lista, você deve verificar isso antes de inseri-la na lista. Neste caso dá para aproveitar e usar `break`, que interrompe o `while`:

```
lista = []
while True:
    palavra = input('digite alguma palavra: ')
    # se a palavra for "sair", sai do loop (e não coloca a palavra na lista)
    if palavra.lower() == 'sair':
        break
    lista.append(palavra)

print(lista)
```

Mas ainda tem outro detalhe: se a palavra for `SAIr`, `saIR` ou qualquer outra variação, isso também fará com que saia do *loop*, já que ao chamar `lower()`, todas serão transformadas em `sair`.

Se você quiser ser mais rígido e só interromper o *loop* se for digitado exatamente "Sair" ou "sair", pode fazer assim:

```
lista = []
while True:
    palavra = input('digite alguma palavra: ')
    # se a palavra for "sair" ou "Sair", sai do loop (e não coloca a palavra na lista)
    if palavra in ('Sair', 'sair'):
        break
    lista.append(palavra)

print(lista)
```

---

Vale lembrar que usar `lower()` funciona para este caso porque estou comparando com uma string que só possui caracteres ASCII (`sair`). Mas para uma comparação que envolva outros caracteres (usados em outros idiomas, como ß ou ﬁ) sugiro ver [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821).